# checking if an textfield is a specific value

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

how can i check if a textfield contains a specific value i tried using the

```
if(x.text = @"hello")
```

however this would work since it would always show me the alertiview i had below this code. I think i am missing something from my comparision however i am unsure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. for compare in general you must use `==` operator, not an assignment operator `=`
2. To compare strings you must use `-isEqualToString:` method as == operator will check if pointers to objects are equal, not the string values they contain.

So the correct code will be

```
if ([x.text isEqualToString:@"hello"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
if ([x.text compare:@"hello"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    // NSString are equal!
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you've posted is an assignment (=), not a comparison (==). Then, what you need is ‘[x.text isEqual:@"hello"]‘. Otherwise you would be comparing pointers and they won't be equal.